# Understanding QgsRasterBlock size using PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm making a QGIS 3 processing algorithm to perform an unsupervised classification with K-Means. When I'm reading the image bands I realized that the following code only works when the image's pixel type is uint8.

(input is a QgsRasterLayer)

```
    #Getting input attributes
    band_count = input.bandCount()
    rows = input.height()
    cols = input.width()
    pixelType = input.dataProvider().dataType(1)

    #Making a matrix to store multiband data
    img = np.zeros((rows * cols, band_count),
           gdal_array.GDALTypeCodeToNumericTypeCode(pixelType))

    #Loading the bands into the matrix
    for b in range(band_count):
        img[:,b] = input.dataProvider().block(b+1, input.extent(), cols, rows).data()
```

When working with a uint16 image, the code returns:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2557248) into shape (1278624)
```

How can I load my band pixels (in any type) into my img array ?

My uint16 image is getting blocks with the double of the size expected.

PS. I can make this work using GDAL, but I only want to use pyqgis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found an answer!

I need to use Numpy frombuffer and gdal_array.GDALTypeCodeToNumericTypeCode to make my *for loop* look like this:

```
    #Loading the bands into the matrix
    for b in range(band_count):
        block = input.dataProvider().block(b+1, input.extent(), cols, rows).data()
        data = np.frombuffer(block, dtype=gdal_array.GDALTypeCodeToNumericTypeCode(pixelType))
        img[:,b] = data
```

PS. In order to use gdal_array I need to import it with:

```
from osgeo import gdal_array
```